# Am I using n-of function incorrectly in netlogo?

Tags: netlogo

I'm creating a code that is supposed to make a certain number of turtles have a status of 1 and the rest have a status of 0, the number is calculated using slider inputs from the interface. I've been trying to make the program use n-of but it turns more than the desired number of turtles into the 1 variety (the turtles are set to status 0 from before).

code below (switch for single is to change to only one turtle and tumble switch is for modelling tumbling and running):

```
to spawn
  ifelse (single = false )
  [create-turtles N  [
    set color black
    set xcor 0
    set ycor 0
    set heading random-float 360
    set status 0
    if (tumble = true)
    [
      print (N * p1 / (p1 + p2))
      ask n-of (N * p1 / (p1 + p2)) turtles [set status 1 set color red]]
    ]
  ]
  [create-turtles 1  [
    set color black
    set xcor 0
    set ycor 0
    set heading random-float 360
    pendown
  ]]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your placement of the `ask n-of` statement.  The code is the brackets after `create-turtles N` is executed for each turtle that is created, so each of the N created turtles is in turn asking n-of ... turtles to set status to 1. You will get many more turned turtles than you want.  Moving the `if (tumble ...` block out of the `create-turtles` block should lead to its being executed only once, after all N turtles are created.

```
to spawn
  ifelse (single = false ) [
    create-turtles N  [
      set color black
      set xcor 0
      set ycor 0
      set heading random-float 360
      set status 0
    ]
    if (tumble = true) [
      print (N * p1 / (p1 + p2))
      ask n-of (N * p1 / (p1 + p2)) turtles [set status 1 set color red]
    ]
  ]
  [create-turtles 1  [
    set color black
    set xcor 0
    set ycor 0
    set heading random-float 360
    pendown
    ]
  ]
end
```